# corrupted characters sometimes inserted in terminal

Tags: terminal, drivers, keyboard

I very often get random "�" characters inserted into my terminal when I type. I think this may be a keyboard driver issue but I'm not sure. I'm using an USB keyboard.

Example:

```
$ ls *lock*
ls: *�lock*: No such file or directory
```

This happens on all kind of terminal emulators (gnome-terminal, xterm, etc) but it never happens in a text editor. Only in terminals. Changing the USB keyboard doesn't fix the issue.

I have a native Ubuntu 16.04 installation running on a tuxedo laptop.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: reference only: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)

Comment: Could this be something due to you slipping on the keys and pressing some modifier key?

Comment: Maybe, but even if i did, it doesn't make sense because what modifier key would produce the replacement character ? also I only see it after I pressed enter. This problem is annoying because i often have to re-type commands.